# Cannot reach EJB exposed as REST service

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, ejb-3.1, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to expose some EJBs as REST web service using JAX-RS annotations.  When I deploy `war` file containing EJB Jar in `WEB-INF/lib` to Wildfly 8, I can see in web admin panel EJB Jar as deployed, But I cannot reach REST endpoints and get 404.

This is content of `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/separated/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is a sample session bean I'm trying to serve as web service and put in `jar` file:

```
@Stateless(name = "TestSessionEJB")
@LocalBean
public class TestSessionBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public AuthenticationSessionBean() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("ep")
    public String testEP() {
        return "Hello from testEP()";
    }
}
```

I cannot reach `testEP` through `/<war_file_name>/separated/ep`.  Added `ejb-jar.xml` descriptor to `WEB-INF/`, still no success.  I made another service with classes compiled and deployed directly in `war` file's `WEB-INF/classes`:

```
@ApplicationPath("/integrated")
public class TestRestApp extends Application {
}

@Path("/ep")
public class TestRestEp {

    @GET
    public String doGet() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Here I can reach `doGet()` through `/<war_file_name>/integrated/ep`.

Am I missing something?  Can I deploy EJBs as separated `jar` files and expose them as REST web services with no wrapper?

**UPDATE:**
I annotated `TestSessionBean` with `ApplicationPath("separated")` and made it extending from `javax.ws.rs.Application`.  Still getting 404 but this time It's different; 404 without "Not Found" body.  If I make an endpoint path same as an endpoint in `TestRestApp`, e.g `@Path("ep")` It maps to endpoint in `TestRestApp` and I get "success" instead of "Hello from testEP()" by navigating to `/<war_file_name>/separated/ep`.  If I annotate a method in `TestSessionBean` with a path not defined in `TestRestApp` result is 404.  I cleared my `web.xml` out of servlet definitions and still same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First

Simply annotating an EJB class's method with JAX-RS annotations will not make the method a JAX-RS resource method. You need to make `TestSessionBean` a root resource class by annotating it with `@Path`, like you did with `TestRestEp`. Or you can make this class a Sub-Resource and have a Root resource pass the request to this class. I'd just stick to the former, if you have no idea what the latter means.

## Second

Keeping in mind Wildfly (JBoss) modular architceture

Stated in the Resteasy (Wildfly's JAX-RS implementation) Reference Guide:

> Resteasy and JAX-RS are automically loaded into your deployment's classpath, **if and only if you are deploying a JAX-RS Application**.

That being said, your web.xml doesn't create a JAX-RS application. You are basically depending on the (default JAX-RS specified) `javax.ws.rs.Application` servlet, which is only loaded if the JAX-RS module is loaded into the Server.

When you have an `Application` subclass, with the  `@ApplicationPath` annotation, this creates a JAX-RS application and the JAX-RS module is loaded into the Server and the classpath will be scanned for resource classes.

Also stated in the JAX-RS spec:

> The resources and providers that make up a JAX-RS application are configured via an application-supplied subclass of `Application`. An implementation MAY provide alternate mechanisms for locating resource classes and providers (e.g. runtime class scanning) but use of `Application` is the only portable means of configuration.

So I would stick to the `Application` subclass. No web.xml needed

Comment: Thanks, It was helpful.  Could you please see my update?  And about your second point, isn't having `TestRestApp` enough for `TestSessionBean` too?  I saw sample codes with empty class extending Application for this setup, though they did not intend to make separated ejb-jar.

Comment: Your application class should not have any resource methods. If you just leave the `TestSessionBean` how it originially was, just adding `@Path("/test")`, if you create an `Application` class say with `@ApplicationPath("/separated")`, then you can access `/separated/test/ep`

Comment: You're right. I made another class for Application setup and annotated `TestSessionBean` with `Path("ep")` and dropped `Path(..)` from method.  It didn't work, but your solution worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example how this would work with `jboss-deployement-strucure.xml`, without subclassing `Application`?

Comment: @JörnHorstmann I removed that statement from the post. I forgot what I was thinking when I posted it. Possibly I was simply thinking along the lines of how to  deploy the jax-rs module in JBOSS, but completely forgetting that even with the module deployed, we still need to declare an application. Only ways I know are either in web.xml or in Application subclass.

Comment: Dear @Paul Samsotha I have a problem with exposing EJB as a Rest in weblogic: Even though I add a class inherited from Application which annotated with `@ApplicationPath("/resources")` , I could not call the stateless web service with class annotation of `@Path("/getdata")` and method annotation of `@GET @Path("/getaccount")`                                      The URL I used in Weblogic is: `http://localhost:7001/resources/getdata/getaccount`